# Php truncate with ascii symbols

Tags: php, arrays, truncate

i have a problem with the Php truncate function...

My code is this:

```
// truncate long word
            $textArray = explode ( " ", $text );
            $DEBUG = 1;
            if ($DEBUG == 1) {
                print_r("// truncate long word");
                print_r($textArray);
                print_r("// END truncate long word");
                print_r("<br>");
            }

            foreach ( $textArray as $key => $word ) {
                if (mb_strlen ($word) > $wordsLenght) {
                    $truncatedWord = mb_substr ($word, 0, $wordsLenght);
                    $textArray [$key] = $truncatedWord . "[...]";
                }
            }
```

Assuming, for example, that the input string is this "cia???☺☻♥♀♂☼•◘○♠♣xas?????!!!!----" (without quotes) this is my result printed as a print_r:

```
    // truncate long wordArray
    (
        [0] => cia???☺☻♥♀♂☼•◘○♠♣xas?????!!!!----
    )
    // END truncate long word

Result ($textArray)
    (
        [0] => cia???☺☻♥♀��[...]
    )
```

As you can see the string is terminated incorrectly, it can be caused by what?

Comment: can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? https://3v4l.org/QcdbP

Comment: Please, see this screenshoot just taken! https://i.imgur.com/GAZaNCN.png ..As you can see the result is not the same as you posted..why? :(

Comment: what's your `$wordsLenght` value, and what's `mb_internal_encoding` returns? which encoding did you used when you saved your php file, and which encoding are you using when you read it on your browser?

Comment: Now i put "mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");" befpre truncate operations (in the first foreach cicle) and the string provided returns perfectly! but if i use french/spanish chars at the end (last array key) i can't see "[...]"...try with this string "sÀà, Ââ, Ææssdsasddssdsasasa"... i get https://i.imgur.com/NUQCvH4.png

Comment: you didn't answer my previous questions, until you do I can't help you more

Comment: In the link i provided you can see the word lenght: 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 16 (for each array key)...mb_internal_encoding returns UTF-8..

Comment: and the file is saved in utf-8 encoding..

Comment: if the file is utf-8-encoded, then you should be able to replicate the problem here: https://3v4l.org/tVV3F -> do it, and provide us a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Here the example you want: https://3v4l.org/jYu4j

Comment: what should be the expected results instead? be aware that `Ææssdsasddssdsasasa`'s length is 19.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title, this problem get worst when using ASCI escape sequences, in a terminal.

Here is the end-up of the battle, using [php-mbstring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

> [mb_strcut()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strcut.php) extracts a substring from a string similarly to
>   mb_substr(), but operates on bytes instead of characters. If the cut
>   position happens to be between two bytes of a multi-byte character,
>   the cut is performed starting from the first byte of that character.
>   **This is also the difference to the substr() function, which would
>   simply cut the string between the bytes and thus result in a malformed
>   byte sequence.**

The following function, as example, will truncate strings by an ANSI red star `*`,at the given length.

It works both sides, the input string can contains ASCI sequences and unicodes, and the output can contain some too, for marking.

```
<?php

function strunkate($me, $at, $by = "*"){
  $l = mb_strlen($me);
  $t = mb_strcut($me,0,$at/2);
  $r = mb_strcut($me,$at/2, $l - $at);
  $me = str_replace($t,rtrim($t),str_replace($r, "\033[31;1m".$by."\e[0m", $me));
  return $me;
}

/* Examples */
echo strunkate("Screenshot at 2019-09-09 02-36-46.png",8);
echo "\n";
echo strunkate("Screenshot \033[1mat 2019-09-09\e[0m 02-36-46Super_long_string_with ansi_escape_sequences.png",8);
echo "\n";
echo strunkate("Screenshot \033[1mat 2019-09-09\e[0m 02-36-46Super_long_string_with ansi_escape_sequences.png",24);

/* Output an ASCI red star. No breaking  */
Scre[31;1m*[0m.png
Scre[31;1m*[0m.png
Screenshot [31;1m*[0mequences.png
```

---

[image: Truncate_ASCI]

Run online: https://3v4l.org/2nJla